# Why is my vue project not loading my js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, frontend

I have a login page that works with a file script.js. When I mount the project for some reason my vue is not loading my js file. I get this on console:
[image]

Which is a template that's on the index.html file (which should not load).

This is how I'm mounting my app:
My App.vue file:

```
<template>
<Login msg="login y registro"/>
</template>
<script>
import Login from "./views/login.vue"
export default {
name: "App",
components:{
Login
  } 
}
</script>
```

My main.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import './assets/css/nav.css';
import axios from "axios"
import VueAxios from "vue-axios"
import LoadScript from 'vue-plugin-load-script';

Vue.use(LoadScript);

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.loadScript("/assets/js/script.js")
.then(() => {
  // Script is loaded, do something
})
.catch(() => {
  // Failed to fetch script
});

Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)


axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/api';


new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

And this is my login.vue file:

```
<template>
```

```
    <div class="contenedor__todo">

        <div class="caja__trasera">
            <div class="caja__trasera-login">
                <h3>¿Ya tienes una cuenta?</h3>
                <p>Iniciar Sesión para entrar en la página</p>
                <button id="btn__Iniciar-Sesión"> Iniciar Sesión</button>
            </div>
            <div class="caja__trasera-register">
                <h3>¿Aún no tienes una cuenta?</h3>
                <p>Registrarse para Iniciar Sesión</p>
                <button id="btn__Registrarse"> Registrarse</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="contenedor__login-register">

            <form action="" class="formulario__login">
                <h2>Iniciar sesión</h2>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Usuario" id="user">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" id="pass">
                <button @click="login()">Entrar</button><br>
                <a href="#">¿Recordar contraseña?</a>
            </form>

            <form action="" class="formulario__register">
                <h2>Registrarse</h2>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" id="nombres">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Apellidos" id="apellidos">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Correo electrónico" id="email">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Número de identificacion" id="idN">
                <input type="checkbox" placeholder="terms">
                <label for ="terms"><a hrefer="#">Al seleccionar esta casilla aceptas nuestro aviso de privacidad, los términos y condiciones</a></label>
                <button @click="register()">Enviar </button >
            
                
            </form>
                
        </div>
    </div>

</main>
</body>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Login',
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  datos:{
      username:"",
      password:"",
      nombres: "",
      apellidos: "",
      email:"",
      id:""
  },
  methods:{
  login(){
      this.datos.username = document.getElementById("user").value;
      this.datos.password = document.getElementById("pass").value;
      let user = {username: this.datos.username, password: this.datos.password};
      let valor = this.axios.post("/autenticar", user);
      if(valor){
          alert("Datos correctos")
      }else{
          alert("Datos incorrectos")
      }
  },
  register(){
      this.datos.nombres = document.getElementById("nombres").value;
      this.datos.apellidos = document.getElementById("apellidos").value;
      this.datos.email = document.getElementById("email").value;
      this.datos.username = document.getElementById("idN").value;
      this.datos.id = document.getElementById("idN").value;
      this.datos.password = document.getElementById("idN").value;
      let usuario = {nombres: this.datos.nombres, apellidos: this.datos.apellidos, email: this.datos.email, username: this.datos.id, password: this.datos.id, _id: this.datos.id};
      this.axios.post("/", usuario)
      .then(res =>{
          alert("Usuario creado correctamente! " + res.data )
      }).catch(err => console.log(err));
     }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped src="../assets/css/estilos.css"></style>
```

Comment: cause <main> is missing?

Comment: and <body> too ?

Comment: You need line numbers. When running a Vue project locally, you can view stack traces in the console, which will give them to you if you don't see them elsewhere.

Comment: @Strella definitely has it

Comment: Please put the whole template part in one code section. For me everything points too a tag which not closes or tags that are mixed.

Comment: @Strella I already did and it's not working, originally the tags are in the file, it's just a pasting mistake in the post. :(

Answer (score 0):

You don't have these two opening tags even if you put closing tags on the bottom.

Put these:

```
<main>
<body>
```

after `<template`> tag

Or simply remove:

```
</main>
</body>
```

Comment: Login.vue is the file I am referring to

Comment: It's still not working :(

Comment: If you use an autoformater and two closingTags are in one column sth is wrong! and </main></body> are in one column!